# Difficulty reading a legend

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend, climate, accuracy-assessment

I have downloaded ACCESS-CM2 global climate model for precipitation prediction from 2021 to 2040. I have opened it in ArcGIS Pro 3.1 but found difficulties understanding the legend. it says Red: band 1, Green: band 2, and Blue: band 3. I tried looking for the metadata but nothing found there. I also tried searching Google but found nothing. Any ideas what does it means for those who works with climate change issues. I am mainly looking for the areas with high precipitation prediction. See the picture if you feel confused.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Raster layers are composed of one or more bands.

Here you have a color raster with three bands (red, green, and blue; i.e. RGB).

For each pixel in the raster, each band has a specific value for that pixel and the sum of the three bands gives you a color for that pixel with x amount of red, y amount of green and z amount of blue.

Add all the pixels together and you have color raster (i.e. an image).

[more complete explanation of raster bands](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-bands.htm)